# Changing global variable from within the drag listener

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to change a global variable by dragging the circle across the d3 svg object:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()  
         .on('dragstart', function() { d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red'); })
         .on('drag', function(d,i) { d3.select(this).attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                                        .attr('cy', d3.event.y); dataset[i] = d; console.log(dataset);})
         .on('dragend', function() { d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black'); });
```

The console log is executed but shows no change, and the dataset is not updated EVER, even after releasing the dragged circle. Is this the asynchronicity I am trying to read about, or some other mistake of mine? The idea is to update the line plot matching the nodes positions.

Comment: I have not used D3 but what if you change the `console.log` as follows: `console.log(dataset, i, dataset[i])` -- does it print what you expected?

Comment: Nope! :( It is the same unchanged value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: you **are** changing the value, your dataset is being updated, that's not the problem.

The problem here is quite simple: `d` is **the same** of `dataset[i]`. Let's proof it:

```js
var dataset = [12, 55, 21, 76, 42];

d3.select("foo")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("foo")
  .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
    console.log("d: " + d + " - dataset[i]: " + dataset[i])
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Thus, when you do:

```
dataset[i] = d
```

You're changing something for that same something.

Here is a demo using your code (almost, since I'm using v4 here). Instead of `dataset[i] = d`, I wrote `dataset[i] = d + "foo"`. Drag a circle and have a look at the console:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var dataset = d3.range(5);

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 20 + 40 * d
  })
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on('start', function() {
      d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red');
    })
    .on('drag', function(d, i) {
      d3.select(this).attr('cx', d3.event.x)
        .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
      dataset[i] = d + "foo";
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataset));
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black');
    }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, you are correct! This was not my intended plan!